# how to add fixed subview over google map top right corner in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

Hell sir,
I am using google Map. My GMSMapView  constraint zero all side. I need to add custom subview  over GMSMapView on top right corner so that I can add some custom button.I have added a subview over GMSMapView. I have added constrain for top right corner. I tried like

```
self.mapView.bringSubviewToFront(self.myview)
```

I map is look bellow..
[image]

When I use **GMSCameraPosition** . It does not show in top right corner.It is disappear. I am using like

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.4, longitude:-122.0, zoom: 12)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

    self.view = mapView
```

I think i am doing something wrong.Can you tell me how to fix my view all time device top right corner over the GMSMapView.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

i think the mistake is  `self.view = mapView`

GMSMapView is like any other UIView 
just add it to your view as SubView , 
setConstraints for it then add your myView to mapView and set your constraints

Comment: I mean make GMSMapView subView of view